# Overwrite SOAP V2 API to get a custom field on Magento 1.X

Tags: soap, magento-1.9, overwrite

I have an application connected to my Magento using the Soap V2 API, to retrieve my orders. But actually I'm unable to get a custom field using a custom module.

I'm trying to get a field call "pickup_point" stored in the "sales_flat_order_address table" via the "salesOrderInfo" method that call the "salesOrderAddressEntity". So I updated the wsdl.xml directly in the core code pool and I was able to retrieve the attribute. But now, I want to create custom module using the local code pool.

So I created a custom module by following many tutorials and I read most of the thread here, but I'm quite lost and I'm not able to have a functional module.

I have the following wsdl.xml at app/code/local/MyModule/PickupPoint/etc :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns:typens="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}"   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
name="{{var wsdl.name}}" targetNamespace="urn:{{var wsdl.name}}">
    <types>
        <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:Magento">
            <import namespace="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" />
            <complexType name="salesOrderAddressEntity">
                <all>
                    <element name="pickup_id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0" />
                </all>
            </complexType>
        </schema>
    </types>
</definitions>
```

Then I have the following config.xml at app/code/local/MyModule/PickupPoint/etc :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <MyModule_PickupPoint>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </MyModule_PickupPoint>
    </modules>
</config>
```

And finally I have the following api.xml at the same location :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <api>
        <resources>
            <sales_order translate="title" module="sales">
                <model>sales/order_api</model>
                <title>Order API</title>
                <acl>sales/order</acl>
                <methods>
                    <list translate="title" module="sales">
                        <title>Retrieve list of orders by filters</title>
                        <method>items</method>
                        <acl>sales/order/info</acl>
                    </list>
                    <info translate="title" module="sales">
                        <title>Retrieve order information</title>
                        <acl>sales/order/info</acl>
                    </info>
                </methods>
                <faults module="sales">
                    <not_exists>
                        <code>100</code>
                        <message>Requested order not exists.</message>
                    </not_exists>
                    <filters_invalid>
                        <code>101</code>
                        <message>Invalid filters given. Details in error message.</message>
                    </filters_invalid>
                    <data_invalid>
                        <code>102</code>
                        <message>Invalid data given. Details in error message.</message>
                    </data_invalid>
                    <status_not_changed>
                        <code>103</code>
                        <message>Order status not changed. Details in error message.</message>
                    </status_not_changed>
                </faults>
            </sales_order>
        </resources>
        <resources_alias>
            <order>sales_order</order>
        </resources_alias>
        <v2>
            <resources_function_prefix>
                <order>salesOrder</order>
            </resources_function_prefix>
        </v2>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <sales translate="title" module="sales">
                    <title>Sales</title>
                    <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                    <order translate="title" module="sales">
                        <title>Order</title>
                        <info translate="title" module="sales">
                            <title>Retrieve orders info</title>
                        </info>
                    </order>
                </sales>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </api>
</config>
```

I've already deleted my magento cache and the wsdl cache available at /tmp/wsdl-*.

Am I missing something about custom module implementation ? Do I need to rewrite the API class by extending Sales_Model_Order_Api_V2 and add my attribute ?